# Change the SRC attribute from a parent iframe

Tags: php, javascript

so, I use an iframe like this: `<iframe src="script.php"></iframe>` (with other attributes of course).

Now, what I am trying to do, is that the script.php does some things, than outputs a JS script, which should change that SRC attribue of the iframe to some other page.

Is that possible?

Comment: Does it explicitly have to be the `src` attribute? Would a `location.href` inside the iframe not do?

Comment: Caution with crossdomain scripting, if applicable.

Comment: I did not remember of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume only one frame, without id or name:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = "http://new.url";
```

If the current frame location is at the same domain:

```
frames[0].location.href = "http://new.url";
```

If you have multiple frames, it's very wise to attach an ID to it. When you want to access the frame through the `frames` object, set a name:

```
<iframe id="myframe" name="a_frame_name" src="script.page"></iframe>

JavaScript:
document.getElementById("myframe").src = "newpage.php";
frames.a_frame_name.location.href = "newpage.php";
frames["a_frame_name"].location.href = "newpage.php";
```

Note: `frames[..].location.href` can only be changed if the main page *and* the frame's location are at the same host, due to the [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: it either did not work, or there is something wrong with my script.php. My script.php echo's something like this: 
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElemenById('aframe').src = 'http://www.google.com';</script>

that does not update the iframe :s

Comment: That was the correct answer.  My guess is that something is going wrong when you're adding the script.  Are you using ajax to get the PHP output? Because if so, you'll need to actually add the script itself to the DOM.

Comment: @user726049 Your code should be:  `document.getElementbyId('iframe').src = 'http://google.com';`. Also, make sure that the IFrame already exists when you execute this function.